# Reverse Geocode Location in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding

My input is a latitude and longitude. I need to use the `reverseGeocodeLocation` function of swift, to give me the output of the locality. The code I have tried to use is

```
            println(geopoint.longitude) 
            println(geopoint.latitude)
            var manager : CLLocationManager!
            var longitude :CLLocationDegrees = geopoint.longitude
            var latitude :CLLocationDegrees = geopoint.latitude

            var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
            println(location)

            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                println(manager.location)

                if error != nil {
                    println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                if placemarks.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark


                    println(pm.locality)
                }


                else {
                    println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
                }
```

in the logs I get

```
//-122.0312186
//37.33233141
//C.CLLocationCoordinate2D
//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It seems that the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`function is failing, which then causes the fatal error in the `reverseGeocodeLocation` function. Have I mucked up the format somewhere?

Comment: You didn't create the CLLocation that has to be passed as the location. The location variable is your case is a CLLocationCoordinate2D meaning that is a co-ordinate. You had to create the CLLocation rather than CLLocationCoordinate2D from the coordinate you created.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

you never reverse geocode the location but you pass in manager.location.

see:
`CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, ...`

I assume that was a copy&paste mistake and that this is the issue - the code itself looks good - almost ;)

### working code

```
    var longitude :CLLocationDegrees = -122.0312186
    var latitude :CLLocationDegrees = 37.33233141
    
    var location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) //changed!!!
    println(location)
    
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        println(location)
        guard error == nil else {
            println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard placemarks.count > 0 else {
            println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            return
        }
        let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
        println(pm.locality)
    })
```

Comment: I want detailed address like Street Name, City, State, Country. Your post provides only City..

Comment: You can watch the additional attributes here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark

Comment: This line doesn't make sense " if error != nil ". If error will occur then it will not be nil.

Comment: Hi, sorry dont follow im afraid. if error != nil { return } is like an early exit, no?

Comment: I have changed it to defensive programming for readability. Hope this will help.

Comment: @BananZ overrode edit rejection others all agreed on and accepted it.  It is ok and doesnt change anything. -- But your edit shouldnt have been made. It would have been better if you you had wrote 'lets use guard statements to make things clearerer TBH ;) -- anyway thanks. Maybe it helps