# swift - How to get my location data and put them in variables for iMessage?

Tags: swift, ios9, core-location, cllocationmanager, clplacemark

Yesterday I asked a question here in [stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502130/cant-figure-out-how-to-embed-my-current-location-in-message-body-correctly-usin/33504912#33504912) about how to embed my current location in message body

I had got an answer and I corrected my code

My code works just fine in console, but i couldn't figure out how to get the data from displayLocationInfo function and store them in variables; then put variables in message body.

I'm sorta new in iPhone development

Any help ?

```
class Location: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation : CLPlacemark?
    var detectLocation : CLLocationManager?
    var locManager = CLLocationManager()


     func viewDidLoad()
    {
        viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }


    func updateLocation()
    {
          locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0
            {
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error with the data.")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
    {

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(placemark.locality)
        print(placemark.postalCode)
        print(placemark.administrativeArea)
        print(placemark.country)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say message body, do you mean a text message or an email or something?

Comment: yeah I mean message text, once the message is created , it should include location data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import MessageUI
```

make your class the correct delegate (this one is for iMessage):

```
MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

make some global variables to store the fields you want to store (set them when you are printing to the console in your current code):

```
class Location: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {


var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation : CLPlacemark?
var detectLocation : CLLocationManager?
var locManager = CLLocationManager()

//put your variables for your message below:
//you should use optionals (?) here but to keep it simple I'm assigning ""
var locality = ""
var postalCode = ""

//set your variables when you are currently printing them in the console:
func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
{

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print(placemark.locality)
    print(placemark.postalCode)
    print(placemark.administrativeArea)
    print(placemark.country)

    //here I set postalcode to be used in the message later
    postalCode = placemark.postalCode

}
//call this function when the user hits a send button
func messageAction() {        
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self    
        messageVC.body = "\(postalCode) is my postalCode"
        self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("User hasn't setup Messages.app")
    }
}

//if you have any code you want to run when the message is done sending put it in
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    switch (result.rawValue) {
    case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Message sent success")
    default:
        return
    }


}
```

Another option would be to make the messageAction() method have perameters that you include in your message. Like messageAction(postalCode: String?, locality: String?, municipality: String?) etc. It really depends on if you want to use these values in other methods globally or not.

**IN RESPONSE TO QUESTIONS FROM POSTER:**

Set a global variable (look in the large code sample above for this line). It makes postalCode a global variable.

```
var postalCode = ""
```

In displayLocationInfo() set this variable to have the location's value:

```
postalCode = placemark.postalCode
```

In messageAction() set the body of the message to use that variable:

```
let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
messageVC.body = "\(postalCode) is my postalCode"
```

This will make a message that says "12345 is my postalCode" in the text message window.

Comment: I know exactly how to implement message code, but I want to embed my location data in message body

I couldn't get the location data from displayLocationInfo function

Comment: Is the console print working properly? Like is it properly printing the information out? If so, then you just store the info in variables like I show above and call them in the message function.

Comment: Ok - so you want to put the stuff you printed out in the console into a message. Look at the code sample above again - it shows making a global variable (line 7) to store the value (in displayLocationInfo()) and then calling that value for the message body (messageAction()). Tell me if that isn't what you are looking for

Comment: Awesome :) glad to help.